# ¿Por qué a veces funciona y a veces no el debugger en javascript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Programo con Visual Studio 2013 y cuándo quiero debuggar jquery o javascript utilizo el comando `debugger;` combinado con la consola del navegador (F12).

A veces, aunque lo tenga puesto y la consola abierta, se salta por completo este campo... ¿Alguien sabe por qué?

para poner un ejemplo...:

```
function test() {
    alert("hola");
    debugger;
    alert("hola2");
}
```

Lo que ocurre es que a veces recibo el alert de "hola" y seguidamente el de "hola2" sin que la consola se pare... Creo que puede estar relacionado con el Visual Studio pero no lo sé...

Comment: Que navegador utilizas para depurar ?

Comment: el debug de codigo javascript poniendo breakpoint en VS solo funciona si usas IE, con otro browser no te va a funcionar

Answer (score 1):

Proba cambiando esto en el BundleConfig.cs

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true
a esto: 
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;
```

Comment: ¿qué es el BundleConfig.cs? ¿Dónde esta? haha lo siento pero no tengo niidea..

Comment: es un paquete de optimización para AspNet.web, ahi normalmente van las configuraciones de optimización y puede ser que el enableotimizations este causando problema. lo mas probable es que no tengas instalado el paquete. Aqui te dejo una guia que te puede solucionar el problema http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/using-browser-link

Comment: gracias! voy a probarlo